# Using chef-zero + docker + kitchen with multiple nodes recipe

Tags: chef-infra, docker, test-kitchen

I'm using Docker + chef-zero + Test Kitchen to test my cookbooks,

As part of my recipe I am searching for other nodes:

```
nodes = search(:node, "*:*")
```

It seems that when converging my kitchen, It raises chef-zero on each container, and therefor the search returns just the node itself.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to test multi-node recipes?

Comment: "It raises chef-zero on each container" - what does that mean?

Comment: for each 'suite' mentioned in my kitchen.yml file, kitchen starts a different docker container, and on each docker container it uses chef-client -z command. ( I think .. or again, i might be missing something )

Comment: Right - each test suite is totally isolated.

Comment: I'm referring to this scenario : [issue-437](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/437), I guess that answers my question. **thanks**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it a [known issue on the project](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/437).